# Sending email from C++

Tags: c++, email

I have a some server which receives connections from clients.
So, what is the elemental way to send email? (without using any non-standard libraries).

And one more question:
if I have a complete php script to send email can I execute it from my C++ programm?

Comment: "So, what is the elemental way to send email? (without using any non-standard libraries)." There isn't one. You need to relax your requirements if you want a solution.

Comment: Ok, so, what is easy way? POCO? Or Vmime? Or something else?

Comment: The "elemental" way is to write an entire SMTP client on top of the socket layer, which is part of the standard libraries.  There is no standard SMTP library, so you either need a 3rd party one or have to write one yourself (no small undertaking.)

Comment: Let's start at the beginning. What OS will you be compiling this with?

Comment: @Joe what socket layer? There's no socket layer in the C++ standard libraries.

Comment: If php can be called from the command line then you can do that from C++ using [system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: you can make the argument that Boost is a standard C++ library.

Comment: Oh, and the other question is I'm not 100% certain, but my guess is definitely no, it isn't possible to call a php script from C++ without using any non-standard libraries.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've got your idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ doesn't have a standard library for communicating via SMTP. You may find a non-standard library that provides this functionality.

If you need to send an email in C++ without the use of a thirdparty library, you will need to write functions that can send SMTP commands through a socket to whatever mail server you wish to use.